# Word 2010 - How can I underline a heading, which was aligned to the right and indented to the left, over the whole text area?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, indentation

I have typeset a heading (heading 1, to be exact) with the following properties:

- alignment of heading 1: right-aligned
- indentation of heading 1: 12 cm (meaning each heading has a horizontal space of 12 cm **on its right**)
- paragraph box/frame of heading 1: underlined

Now the problem is that the underline only goes to the very end of the last letter of each heading, i.e. the indentation border 12 cm from the right text area. I'd like to have the underline go to the very right of the text area. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a full line across the page, take a look at the solution to this question:
[Using Word, how can I create a document that looks like this?](https://superuser.com/questions/884609/using-word-how-can-i-create-a-document-that-looks-like-this)

> 1. Select "Borders and Shading..." from the dropdown in the ribbon ("Paragraph" pane in the "Home" tab)
> 2. Select the top and bottom borders on the right pane of the Borders tab
> 3. Optionally, for spacing between the border and the text, select "Options..."
> 4. In the dialog, enter the spacing that you want

Comment: This is not it. The lines which are drawn using this method adhere to the indentation done from the right, hence the line does not go across the whole page (text area to be exact).