# Using Word, how can I create a document that looks like this?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to create a document with this format, but having a lot of trouble.

Particularly the text centered and bordered between 2 parallel lines (the portion circled in red).

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: In Word, how do I create 2 parallel lines that go above and below text, with the text centered in between?

Comment: my answer does that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a border to the paragraph.

[image]

1. Select "Borders and Shading..." from the dropdown in the ribbon ("Paragraph" pane in the "Home" tab)
2. Select the top and bottom borders on the right pane of the Borders tab
3. Optionally, for spacing between the border and the text, select "Options..."
4. In the dialog, enter the spacing that you want

Comment: This is rather difficult to follow. Could you just number the circles and list the steps as text below?

Comment: @zeel - edited to add steps